# Bash read dictionary file

Tags: bash, dictionary

I have a dictionary file, call it 1.txt with the following content:

```
app1=1

app2=10

app3=2

app1=8
```

and so on.

From a bash script I would like to:

1. call 1.txt
2. read its content line by line
3. get key into variable A
4. get value into variable B

I tried:

`var1=${for KEY in "${!dict[@]}"; do echo $KEY; done`

`var2=${for KEY in "${!dict[@]}"; do echo $dict[$KEY]}; done`

which works just fine but I do not know how to wrap this into a bash function that calls the dictionary set on another file.

Would you please point out on this?

Comment: How did you assign `dict`? If you can do it, most of your questions may have been solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this is what you want.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A dict

# Read the file into associative array "dict"
read_into_dict () {
    while read -r line; do
        [[ $line = *=* ]] && dict[${line%%=*}]=${line#*=}
    done < "$1"
}

read_into_dict 1.txt

# Print out the dict
for key in "${!dict[@]}"; do
    printf '%s=%s\n' "$key" "${dict[$key]}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

@M. Nejat Aydin,
I tried the following at localhost.
``

```
$ cat 73095065.sh
#!/bin/bash
declare -A dict
for EACHLN in $(cat 1.txt)
do
KEY=$(echo "$EACHLN" | sed "s/=.//;")
VALUE=$(echo "$EACHLN" | sed "s/.=//;")
if [ "${dict[$KEY]}" = "" ]
then
dict["$KEY"]="$VALUE"
else
echo "FOUND DUPLICATE KEY AT 1.txt"
echo "HENCE NOT SETTING dict["$KEY"] TO $VALUE AGAIN."
echo "CURRENT LINE: $EACHLN"
echo "OLD dict value: $KEY=${dict["$KEY"]}"
fi
done
echo "EXISTING DICT VALUES:"
for KEY in "${!dict[@]}"
do
echo "KEY $KEY VALUE ${dict[$KEY]}"
done

Sample output:

$ ./73095065.sh
FOUND DUPLICATE KEY AT 1.txt
HENCE NOT SETTING dict[app1] TO 8 AGAIN.
CURRENT LINE: app1=8
OLD dict value: app1=1
EXISTING DICT VALUES:
KEY app3 VALUE 2
KEY app2 VALUE 10
KEY app1 VALUE 1
```

Comment: Please enclose your code in a code block